# How to use Selenium to dump whole DOM tree of a Web page?

Tags: java, selenium, dom, web-crawler

I am going to build a Web crawler by analyzing the content of a Web page. I am using Selenium Java API to render the page and try to build the complete DOM for furthuer analysis.

However, I found that the API that Selenium provides can only be used to find elements by tags or id/class names. How could I dump the complete DOM tree by using Selenium? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can run execute script if your purpose is just to get entire DOM as a string like

```
executeScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML");
```